# How to Allow Samba Shares for Domain users?

Tags: server, permissions, samba, file-sharing, active-directory

I have a samba server with shares using POSIX ACL.
We installed the Active Directory domain controller  by using [Turnkey image](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/domain-controller), I joined Ubuntu Server to the domain following [this](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_21.04&p=realmd)  , Installed Kerberus-User, and joined Samba into Domain using Webmin, which worked.
After webmin joined Samba Server into the domain, Config from this:

```
[global]
workgroup = COMPANY
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

into this:

```
[global]
realm = company.lan
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
store dos attributes = yes
map to guest = bad user
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
logging = file
unix password sync = yes
obey pam restrictions = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
max log size = 10000
security = ADS
workgroup = COMPANY
pam password change = yes
map acl inherit = yes
server role = standalone server
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
usershare allow guests = yes
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
vfs objects = acl_xattr
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
winbind trusted domains only = yes
```

and samba restarted without issue, it worked but now I cannot authenticate.

my desired goal is that:

1. Old linux/Samba users can still authenticate, for support of non-domain devices
2. domain users, such as test@company.lan can access the shares

Example of my Share:

```
[test]
path = /Shares/test
inherit acls = yes
inherit permissions = yes
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0660
force directory mode = 2770
hide special files = yes
hide files = /~$*/
```

Permissions are:

```
root@server:~# getfacl /Shares/test
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: Shares/test
# owner: www-data
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:Everyone:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

and my user is in the group:

```
getent group | grep Everyone
Everyone:x:1007:tomcat,Unix-user,COMPANY+test
```

so to recap,
Before joining the domain Unix-user could use samba share, After joining no one can use samba shares, the Desired outcome is that both Unix-user and test@company.lan can use samba shares.

I'm sure I either didn't input the domain user correctly or something,but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David Hello, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Don't use realmd and sssd, you only get authentication. You need to use winbind and one of the idmap backends, see here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member . You will have to allow guest access for anything outside the  domain.